# Firebase FCM null token

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a (super) basic FCM app in my browser, and following the Firecasts on YouTube, I've hit a wall.

Where I'm supposed to have a token printed by calling `messaging.getToken()` and logging the token to the console, I get `null` instead.

My code is as follows:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>'
```

I only need the FCM parts of the Firebase SDK (and I've tried this with all of it fetched too).

```
<script>
var config = {
    apiKey: "MY-API-KEY-IS-HERE-BUT-I-REMOVED-IT-FOR-STACKOVERFLOW",
    authDomain: "DOMAIN.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://DOMAIN.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "PROJECTS_ID",
    storageBucket: "DOMAIN.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "ID"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function(e=null) {
      console.log("Granted!"+e);
      return messaging.getToken();
  })
  .then(function(token) {
      console.log(token);
  })
      .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Error! :: "+err);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made a wrong function chain,

`2nd then()` have to be after `getToken()`,

```
<script>
var config = {
    apiKey: "MY-API-KEY-IS-HERE-BUT-I-REMOVED-IT-FOR-STACKOVERFLOW",
    authDomain: "DOMAIN.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://DOMAIN.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "PROJECTS_ID",
    storageBucket: "DOMAIN.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "ID"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function(e=null) {
      console.log("Granted!"+e);
      return messaging.getToken()
          .then(function(token) {
                console.log(token);
           }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log("Error! :: "+err);
           });
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```